# Android Places SDK returns at most 5 results

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm using autocomplete service of Android Places SDK to show location results based on user's query. I'm using following code to fetch results as per user's query:

```
public void showPredictions(String query) {
    GeoDataClient geoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(context);
    Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results = geoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(query, null, null);

    try {
        Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse autocompletePredictions = results.getResult();
        ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> predictions = DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);

        showPredictions(predictions);
    } catch (RuntimeExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code works fine and I'm able to see results based on user's query. But the problem is that the Places SDK returns at most 5 results for a given query. So my question is how to make Android Places SDK return more than 5 results?